# MacAgent Xamarin

Tags: .net, xamarin

Eu tenho o Visual Studio 2017 instalado no Windows. E no meu Mac o Xcode.

Para compilar projetos no VS 2017 via Windows, eu posso conectar a um Mac, Via MacAgent.

Minha dúvida é, no meu Mac eu preciso apenas do Xcode instalado ou o Visual Studio For Mac Xamarin também?

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a documentação ([Link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/#Macintosh)) :

1. Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11) ou superior
2. Xamarin iOS SDK.
3. Apple’s Xcode(7+) IDE and iOS SDK (última versão recomendada).

   De acordo com os requisitos não é necessário (VS2017 for mac ou Xamarin Studio). Para obter o instalador autônomo `Xamarin iOS SDK` é necessário cadastra-se cadastre-se no fórum ([Xamarin](https://auth.xamarin.com/account/register)), depois vá em: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads.

Segue o link do instalador mais recente até a presenta data: https://xamarin.azureedge.net/installer/2017-01-10/XamarinInstaller.dmg

Embora não seja necessário, a vantagem da instalação do `VS2017` é a possibilidade de atualização para novas versões de forma mais simples. Já com instalador autônomo não sei como isso seria possível, talvez só verificando manualmente na página de download:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que a instalação em conjunto com o `VS2017 for MAC` seja a melhor opção mesmo que não o utilize diretamente para desenvolvimento.

Documentação como conectar ao MAC:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Caso queira instalar VS for MAC:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation

Answer (score 0):

No Mac você vai precisar do **Xcode** e *Visual Studio* ou *Xamarin Studio*, juntamente com todas as SDK (geralmente baixadas junto com o xamarin studio ou visual studio).

Não esqueça também de liberar o Login remoto no Mac,
qualquer coisa [veja a documentação aqui](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/)